# `Improper Operand type: data error` with MASM 5.00

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, emu8086, dosbox

I'm having trouble in converting my file from EMU8086 assembly syntax to MASM 5.00 syntax and I get the error:

> Improper operand type: DATA

[image]

My code is:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
x db ?
y db ?
z db ?
q db 10,13, 'First Digit  $'
r db 10,13, 'Second Digit  $'
s db 10,13, 'Product  $'

.code
mov ax,data
mov DS,ax
lea dx,q
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov x,al
lea dx,r
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov y,al
mul x
mov z,al
aam
add ah,30h
add al,30h
mov bx,ax
lea dx,s
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl,bh
int 21h
mov ah,2
mov dl,bl
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end
```

Comment: copy/paste the text of the error message, and show which line that is.  Does emu8086 want `mov ax, @data` for the segment base?  Some assemblers do.  Also, are you using dosbox or are you using emu8086?  emu8086 has its own emulator.  (8086 is a tag synonym for emu8086 for some reason.  But DOSBox emulates a 386 at least so the right tag is more likely x86-16 if you aren't using emu8086.)

Comment: You are new to programming and want to start with assembly and emulating? That's sounds like a long, stony path. Maybe start with a more beginner-friendly environment, such as Python or Java...

Comment: A good way to start would be using a high level language that has the possibility for _Intel Assembly_ inline blocks which can access the variables in the scope of the high level language. Unfortunately, I don't know of any current one (Turbo C and Turbo Pascal have matched this criteria back in the days).

Comment: Why does it have to be Intel Assembly syntax? GCC (for C and C++) has sophisticated inline assembly mechanisms for the GNU GAS / AT&T syntax.

Comment: @Erlkoenig : sophisticated enough, but error prone if you don't know how to properly handle all the nuances of constraints. For new people I would highly recommend against GCC's inline assembly and do assembly in separate assembly modules (files) and link them in. As well, unless you are using the ia16 GCC project, GCC outputs bastardized 16-bit code that has 32-bit operand prefix overrides. The Intel assembly of the old high level languages like Turbo-C that had inline assembly is far more forgiving than GCC's inline assembly, but the tradeoff is that it produces less efficient code.

Comment: Yes that's right, the GCC inline assembly is quite complicated. Alas, there isn't a large market for easy-to-use inline-assembly in high-level languages :-)

Answer (score 1):

EMU8086 uses a rather relaxed MASM like syntax. When using the simplified segment directives with actual MASM you have to reference the segment names with an `@` sign (and you drop the period `.`) from the name. The `.data` segment should be referenced as `@data` and not `data`. The [MASM documentation](http://bytepointer.com/masm/index.htm) describes it this way:

> @code, @data, etc.: **For each of the primary segment directives, there is a corresponding equate with the same name, except that the equate starts with an at sign (@) but the directive starts with a period**. For example, the @code equate represents the segment name defined by the .CODE directive. Similarly, @fardata represents the .FARDATA segment name and @fardata? represents the .FARDATA? segment name. The **@data equate represents the group name shared by all the near data segments**. It can be used to access the segments created by the .DATA, .DATA?, .CONST, and .STACK segments.

The code:

```
mov ax,data
mov DS,ax
```

Should be written as:

```
mov ax,@data
mov DS,ax
```

---

### Additional Notes

**This doesn't apply to MASM 5.xx that you are using**. In newer versions of MASM (6.00+) the assembler can generate the required startup code that sets the segment registers appropriately for the `model` specified by using the `.startup` directive. With the newer version of MASM (and TASM) you could have replaced:

```
.code
mov ax,@data
mov DS,ax
...
```

with:

```
.code
.startup
...
```